# how to integrate spotfire analyatic report with common user credentials into angular application?

Tags: angular, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer

We are currently trying to integrate spotfire with our angular application and we are stuck.

how to integrate spotfire analyatic report with common user credentials? We call the api with url and param and there are some options to show/hide menu etc.

But I want this visualization to be seemless with my other contents of the page. Users should not be asked to login to spotfire.

How can we allow anonymous access and how can we hide the login button on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tibco/spotfire-wrapper ?

This is a lib that eases the integration of Spotfire in an Angular App or even inside pure raw HTML like this

```
<spotfire-viewer
  url="https://spotfire-next.cloud.tibco.com"
  path="Samples/Introduction to Spotfire" 
  page="Example dashboard" 
</spotfire-viewer>

<script src="https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/spotfire-wrapper/blob/master/dist/spotfire-wrapper.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The login button can be hidden from the customization parameters.

var customizationInfo = {
    showAbout : false,
    showAnalysisInformationTool : false,
    showAuthor : false,
    showClose : false,
    showCustomizableHeader : false,
    showDodPanel : false,
    showExportFile : false,
    showExportVisualization : false,
    showFilterPanel : false,
    showHelp : false,
    showLogout : false,
    showPageNavigation : false,
    showReloadAnalysis : false,
    showStatusBar : false,
    showToolBar : false,
    showUndoRedo : false
}

Believe it's logout.

For the seamless no login experience you'll have to save you dxp in a library folder that has anonymous login access.

Customization - Show/Hide UI Components
https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-javascript-api-overview

Comment: Thanks. I am able to allow anonymous access. But Login button is still shown. ShowLogout is not working.

Comment: toggle on and off the rest of the parameters. one will hide it.